# Convert hebrew strings to Hex in Python

Tags: python, unicode, hex, hebrew

I have this code that gets as input some strings in Hebrew and outputs the Hex value of the strings.

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

def str_to_hex(string):
    hex_str = ""
    '... some code ...'
    return hex_str

my_input = raw_input("Enter string: ")
hex_value = str_to_hex(my_input)
print "Your String was: %s\t Hex Value:%s" % (my_input,hex_value)
print result.encode('utf-8')
```

Any Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code using [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import binascii


my_input = raw_input("Enter string: ")
hex_value = binascii.hexlify(my_input)
print "Your String was: %s\t Hex Value:%s" % (my_input,hex_value)
print hex_value
```

Answer (score 2):

you may use `encode()` with the 'hex' parameter:

```
>>> 'blahblah'.encode('hex')
'626c6168626c6168'
```

your function become:

```
def str_to_hex(string):
    return string.encode('hex')
```